# Printing strings of length k from given subset

Tags: c, string

Am trying to use recursion to print k length sets from given input.
Example of what I want :

input:

```
3
a b c
```

output:

```
aaa
aab
aba
.
.
```

so on.

I am somehow getting garbage values!

```
int klength(char input[],char output[],int size, int k, int curr){
    int i=0;
    if(k<=0)
    {
    puts(output);
    return 0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        output[curr]=input[i]; // **EDIT**
        printf("current output %s\n",output);
        klength(input,output,size,k-1,++curr);
        printf(" after recursion %s]n,output);
    }
}
```

Can someone please point me to my mistake?! I can't somehow find my mistake and am running a little short on time :\ Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if(ch=='\n'||'\0')` is wrong. Use `if(ch=='\n'|| ch =='\0')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
klength(input,output,size,k-1,++curr);
```

here you increment `curr` each time in the loop, which means it increases rapidly and eventually overflows your output buffer.  You want

```
klength(input,output,size,k-1,curr+1);
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks works now but what exactly went wrong i did not get? ++curr should also increment it the same number of times as curr+1 shouldnt it?

Comment: @joanOfArc No. The former modifies the value of curr, whereas the latter only passes the result of the arithmetic operation of curr+1, so curr itself is not changed.